# Docker File Install Microsoft ODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, pyodbc

I have application which deployed via Docker, in my application i am accessing the `Azure SQL` ,  so. my connection string look like this

```
mssql+pyodbc://<user>@<domain>:<password>@<conn_string>.database.windows.net:1433/<db>?driver={'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'}
```

My Docker File :

```
# Configure the MS SQL query drivers
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt update 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```

I am getting below error :

```
Can't open lib '{'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'' : file not found (0)
```

Can anyone help me how to properly configure the driver?

Comment: Did you mean to include the `'` characters inside `driver={'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'}`?

Comment: Aside... once you've fixed the above issue a common mistake is to reference the wrong drivers from packages.microsoft.com: execute `docker run -it --rm YourImageNameHere cat /etc/os-release` and confirm that it is actually using a Debian 10 distro.